# Opening Port 443 is not working in Ubuntu VM of Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, port

I have tried to open the port 443 and it is not working. I have successfully opened the port 80 without any problem but when I do the same for the 443 it is not working.

I tried it from the Networking tab of the VM page. here is the screenshot

[image]

I am testing it with different tools online to see if the port is opened or not. And all of them is saying that the port 443 is close but the 80 is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the application is listening on the said port and check os level firewall allows that port

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I have checked the firewal at the os level but that one is inactive ... I done follow what you mean by "check the application is listening on the said port ". Which application we are speaking here ?

Comment: whichever you are trying to access. something must listen on 443 for you to get a response

Comment: that was exactly the problem I needed to listen to the 443 in order the test of openness be passed. thanks.